# Background Colour Change At Run Time Android

Tags: android, background-color

I am Using LinearLayout to set BackGround Shape which has curve Corner. I have created drawable XML file. When I try to change LinearLayout backGround Colour at RunTime In My Activity,  the colour appears is reflected in the Layout but background shape is not been applied. Need help on this

My layout.xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout        
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                   
            android:id="@+id/month_card"
            android:backgroundTint="@drawable/circle_corner_rectangle"
            app:backgroundTintMode="src_over">
```

shape.xml file

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
    <corners android:radius="500dip" />
    <stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <gradient android:angle="-90"/>
</shape>
```

Finally setting it on runtime inside the activity

```
layout.setBackgroundColor(colorList.get(position));
```

Comment: You want to change layout background or background tint?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
    final int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    layout.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.circle_corner_rectangle) 
);
} else {
    layout.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.circle_corner_rectangle));
}
```

instead of

```
layout.setBackgroundColor(colorList.get(position));
```

Comment: but i am set colour from arraylist not drawable shape defined colour

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

circle_corner_rectangle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#E0F2F1" />
    <corners android:radius="6dp"/>
</shape>

 <RelativeLayout        
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                   
        android:id="@+id/month_card"
        android:backgroundTint="@drawable/circle_corner_rectangle">
```

Comment: how to set colour at run time

Comment: setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, R.drawable. circle_corner_rectangle)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this work in your case

```
        val shape = GradientDrawable()
        shape.shape = GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE
        shape.setStroke(mStrokeWidth!!,mStrokeColor!!)
        shape.cornerRadius = 2f
        imageView.background = shape
```

> This code is in kotlin

Comment: i am not use kotlin bro

Comment: i am not use kotlin

Comment: Use GradientDrawable() for run time color change. That code was just for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this ,,

```
   layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#20A4E8"));
  (or)
   layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

just add another xml file You want and add this code in run time

```
   layout.setBackgroundTintList(getContext.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.your_xml_name));
```

Comment: @karthik just do that

Comment: i will try bro.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        Drawable drawable = yourView.getBackground();

        try {
            drawable.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor(yourColor), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```